# Typing declaration disambiguate Object or Function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make the [Dockerode run typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1bcc829993a52a4f8b83abcc4fe07997a29d8027/types/dockerode/index.d.ts#L1249-L1253) match that of [the implementation](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode/blob/5ac15d82be325173c6f42c3e7b1d13a61a6d4bf1/lib/docker.js#L1389-L1395). The problem is that when I call `run` no matter what TypeScript sees the return value as a `Promise`.

I think the problem is that TypeScript is matching a `function` to an `Object` and cannot disambiguate the overloads of `run` in the type declaration. Though I'll admit I'm a bit stumped as to why.

[I've made a small example in a TypeScript Playground that I think exemplifies the error.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20index.d.ts%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20EventEmitter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20emit()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20RunCallback%20%3D%20(error%3A%20any%2C%20result%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%2C%20value%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20run(one%3A%20string%2C%20two%3A%20string%5B%5D%2C%20option1%3A%20Object%2C%20option2%3A%20Object)%3A%20Promise%3Cnumber%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20run(one%3A%20string%2C%20two%3A%20string%5B%5D%2C%20option1%3A%20Object%2C%20callback%3A%20RunCallback)%3A%20EventEmitter%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20Bar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20run(one%3A%20string%2C%20two%3A%20string%5B%5D%2C%20option1%3A%20Object%2C%20callback%3A%20RunCallback)%3A%20EventEmitter%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20worker.ts%0D%0Afunction%20callback(a%3A%20Error%2C%20data%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%2C%20container%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20broken%3A%20EventEmitter%20%3D%20new%20Foo().run(''%2C%20%5B''%5D%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20callback)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20works%3A%20EventEmitter%20%3D%20new%20Bar().run(''%2C%20%5B''%5D%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20callback)%3B%0D%0A)

```js
// index.d.ts
declare class EventEmitter {
  emit(): void;
}

type RunCallback = (error: any, result: string | null, value: number) => void;

declare class Foo {
  run(one: string, two: string[], option1: Object, option2: Object): Promise<number>;
  run(one: string, two: string[], option1: Object, callback: RunCallback): EventEmitter;
}

declare class Bar {
  run(one: string, two: string[], option1: Object, callback: RunCallback): EventEmitter;
}

// worker.ts
function callback(a: Error, data: string | null, container: number) {}

const broken: EventEmitter = new Foo().run('', [''], {}, callback);
const works: EventEmitter = new Bar().run('', [''], {}, callback);
```

Notice that in the playground `broken` does not compile because `broken` is coming back as a `Promise` not `EventEmitter`. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Everything is an `Object` in `Javascript` including functions. This is why the function matches the object overload.

Overload order matters, and putting the function overload first will match the appropriate overload:

```
// index.d.ts
declare class EventEmitter { emit(): void; }

type RunCallback = (error: any, result: string | null, value: number) => void;

declare class Foo {
  run(one: string, two: string[], option1: Object, callback: RunCallback): EventEmitter;
  run(one: string, two: string[], option1: Object, option2: Object): Promise<number>;
}

// worker.ts
function callback(a: Error, data: string | null, container: number) { }

const c1: EventEmitter = new Foo().run('', [''], {}, callback);
const c2: Promise<number> = new Foo().run('', [''], {}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the exact reason why `RunCallback` is assignable to `Object`. Perhaps due to the nature of functions in JavaScript (see [this](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/typescript-2-2-the-object-type#the-object-type))

However, replacing `option1` and `option2` with something else (`Record`), seems to achieve the result you're looking for. I think that's more inline with what you're looking for, anyways.

[Here's a working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20index.d.ts%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20EventEmitter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20emit()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20RunCallback%20%3D%20(error%3A%20any%2C%20result%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%2C%20value%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20run(one%3A%20string%2C%20two%3A%20string%5B%5D%2C%20option1%3A%20Record%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E%2C%20option2%3A%20Record%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E)%3A%20Promise%3Cnumber%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20run(one%3A%20string%2C%20two%3A%20string%5B%5D%2C%20option1%3A%20Record%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E%2C%20callback%3A%20RunCallback)%3A%20EventEmitter%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20Bar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20run(one%3A%20string%2C%20two%3A%20string%5B%5D%2C%20option1%3A%20Object%2C%20callback%3A%20RunCallback)%3A%20EventEmitter%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20worker.ts%0D%0Afunction%20callback(a%3A%20Error%2C%20data%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%2C%20container%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20broken%3A%20EventEmitter%20%3D%20new%20Foo().run(''%2C%20%5B''%5D%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20callback)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20works%3A%20EventEmitter%20%3D%20new%20Bar().run(''%2C%20%5B''%5D%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20callback)%3B%0D%0A)